# R dynamically update a graph given a time frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, plotly, ggmap

I am trying to build a map with ggmap which get updated given a time frame, I get what I want except that the points are connected to each other, there are lines coming from nowhere

here is an example of the data set

```
  FINAL <- tribble(
  ~Country.EN, ~UWY, ~amount_claims, ~latitude, ~longitude, ~Continent, 
  "ALBANIA" , 2009  ,  34.25  ,     41.15333  ,  20.16833   , "Europe",
  "ALBANIA" , 2011  ,  234.00 ,     41.15333,    20.16833 ,   "Europe",
  "ALBANIA" , 2012  ,  345.63 ,     41.15333,    20.16833 ,   "Europe",
  "ALBANIA" , 2013  ,  45.84  ,     41.15333  ,  20.16833   , "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2007  ,  567.84 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2008  ,  345.41 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2009  ,  456.11 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2010  ,  321.36 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2011  ,  123.29 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2012  ,  345.06 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe")
```

here is the code

```
test <- get_map(location = "Europe", maptype = "terrain", source = "google", zoom = 4)
map <- ggmap(test) +
geom_point(data = FINAL, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, frame=year, size=amount_claims)) 
ggplotly(map,width=900,height=500)
```

here is my output [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsfEm.png), I clearly want to get rid of the line and show only the point, this pb occurs only when I call plotly

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: I ve updated my post

Comment: It still not reproducible. Please use `dput()` to add your dataset to your post.

Answer (score 0):

All I changed was the `frame = UWY` option in `geom_point(aes())`. I got what you wanted to get, I believe. No such line

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(plotly)

FINAL <- tribble(
  ~Country.EN, ~UWY, ~amount_claims, ~latitude, ~longitude, ~Continent, 
  "ALBANIA" , 2009  ,  34.25  ,     41.15333  ,  20.16833   , "Europe",
  "ALBANIA" , 2011  ,  234.00 ,     41.15333,    20.16833 ,   "Europe",
  "ALBANIA" , 2012  ,  345.63 ,     41.15333,    20.16833 ,   "Europe",
  "ALBANIA" , 2013  ,  45.84  ,     41.15333  ,  20.16833   , "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2007  ,  567.84 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2008  ,  345.41 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2009  ,  456.11 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2010  ,  321.36 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2011  ,  123.29 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe",
  "AUSTRIA" , 2012  ,  345.06 ,     47.51623,    14.55007 ,   "Europe")

test <- get_map(location = "Europe", maptype = "terrain", source = "google", zoom = 4)
map <- ggmap(test) +
  geom_point(data = FINAL, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, frame=UWY, size=amount_claims)) 
ggplotly(map,width=900,height=500)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add the data points that are problematic with `dput`. The Albania and Austria examples I made into a tribble don't present that problem

Comment: I not sure to understand this, do you want me to print the output of the dput command? Actually I have copied paste your example, I don't know if it's related to jupyter or to ggplotly

Comment: The problematic output seems to be in Britain and France but the sample dataset you provide doesn't have these countries or the issue you're having. Could you provide the datapoints that produced the issue?